# Percent stacked barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to create a stacked bar plot using `ggplot2` in `R`.

For example, for this data

```
x <- 1:5
y1 <- c("m", "m", "m" ,"m", "n")
y2 <- c("m", "m", "n" ,"n", "p")
colors <- c("m" = "red", "n" = "green", "p" = "blue")
```

what the plot should look like (ideally!) is the first row `red-red-red-red-green`and stacked on this row `red-red-green-green-blue` and the lenght of each row is 1.

What I have so far is

```
df <- data.frame(x = x, y1 = y1, y2 = y2)

colors <- c("m" = "red", "n" = "green", "p" = "blue")

ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = y1), position = "stack", color = "black") +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = y2), position = "stack", color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors)
```

but the output is
[image]
which is not what we are looking for.

Could someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to do this if you pivot your data into long format, and use a single `geom_bar` with a reversed stack:

```r
ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -x), aes(x = x)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = value, group = interaction(name, value)), 
           color = "black", position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was thinking about. But for `x==1` and `x==2`, is it possible to show each stack separately?